# Google Analytics - Google Organic traffic with backslash

Tags: google-analytics, infinite-scroll

We have recently rolled out an infinite scroll feature in the site that could be generating this issue but we are not sure why/what is causing this. Every page visit and event is reported correctly, but in some cases the page view is prefixed with `/`, (e.g. `/https://www...`). It is only happening in Organic traffic from Google. Any ideas would be more than welcome. We included a canonical link in those pages that contains infinite scroll. As a check we did run a crawler and there are no links in the site like those so not sure how to find the error source.

Comment: How does infinite scroll interact with pageviews? In particular, are you sending additional pageviews to track scrolling down?

Comment: Thanks. Found the issue! A `pageView` event was fired using absolute url instead of relative url. Changing it seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: Great! I thought (hoped) it was something like that. :-)